# PHP UDP Server with Arduino as Client

Tags: php, udp

I have programmed arduino to send massage to udp port 8888 when button pressed, and is working fine when I used third party software such as Socket test, but I am trying to use below php code to receive the massage.

The code([Not my Code](http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-php/)) works, but the result show up when we get fatal errors and not when I send the massage(Press Button)

Below is sample of result(all result show together and not when I press Button):

```
Socket created Socket bind OK Waiting for data ... 10.10.1.48 : 8888 --YellowWaiting for data ... 10.10.1.48 : 8888 -- GreenWaiting for data ... 10.10.1.48 : 8888 -- YellowWaiting for data ... 10.10.1.48 : 8888 -- GreenWaiting for data ... 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Push\udp.php on line 38
```

Below is the code:

```
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

 if ( ! socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) 
{ 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)); 
    exit; 
}
// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0" , 8888) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

//Do some communication, this loop can handle multiple clients
while(1)
{
    echo "Waiting for data ... \n";

    //Receive some data
    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;
    usleep(100000); // debuging purpose
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    //Send back the data to the client
    socket_sendto($sock, "OK " . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
}

socket_close($sock);
```